# Identifying multiple instances of same component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two instances of the same component, say `<parent>`, on the same page. This  component has 3 child levels, lets call them, `<childL1>`, `<childL2>` and `<childL3>`. So, I have two instances of `<childL3>` as well.

Now, I want to identify which `<childL3>` belongs to which `<parent>` component. I don't want to pass parent id through 3 child levels using @Input decorator (which seems to be the only option I have currently). And using the service, we can't identify the child components because both childL3 would be subscribed to the same service.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I asume you are using content-projection? Just to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "parents" has an "id", you can iterate over the DOM

Imagine your parent component has a selector `app-parent`, you can use in your children

```
  parentId: string = null;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    //see that you ask about the selector of the parent
    const sections = document.getElementsByTagName('app-parent');
    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      if (sections[i].contains(this.el.nativeElement))
        this.parentId = sections[i].getAttribute('id');
    }
  }
```

But this not give you the "parent" (you can not access to the parent component only the "html" of the parent and the attributes)

Comment: thanks a lot Eliseo. Sorry I forgot to thank you earlier.

Comment: I did a bit differently for some reason. Instead of searching the child inside parent element. I searched the closest item with parent tag.
But thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inject the correct parent component into your `<childL3>`. Just try:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-l3',
  templateUrl: './child-l3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-l3.component.scss']
})
export class ChildL3Component {

  constructor(private parent: ParentComponent) {

  }
}
```

Each ChildL3 should get the correct parent from its own component tree.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. parent is not being set. Anyway, I can't do this because in my case, ChildL3 component is heavily used by different parent components (parent1, parent2,3 etc.). So, I can't inject each and every parent component either.

Comment: If that be the case you could always use a directive and inject it with the `@Optional` decorator in the constructor. Considering your requirements there will be a bit of jank to deal with regardless of how you decide to implement it.